# Would a nitrogen atom with an extra electron and a positron in its nucleus (that didn't annihilate) have identical properties to oxygen?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms

As said.

And if there's a problem with a positron, lets just say the nucleus somehow had an extra positive charge at its nucleus. Since all chemical reactions are the movement of valence electrons, wouldn't nitrogen have the same properties?

Comment: The energy levels of the electrons depend on the charge on the nucleus.

Comment: it is charge that organizes the chemistry.  Different atomic masses with the same charge are called isotopes and have the same chemical properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're asking whether a nucleus with the same mass as a nitrogen nucleus and the same charge as an oxygen nucleus would form an atom indistinguishable from an oxygen atom. That is, if the charge of the nucleus stays constant does a change in the mass of the nucleus make a difference?

An alternative way of phrasing this would be to consider isotopes of oxygen e.g. ${}^{14}\text{O}$ or ${}^{15}\text{O}$, and ask if their atoms would all be the same.

Assuming this is what you are asking, the answer is that the atoms would be very similar but there would be small differences in their energy levels. We normally assume the nucleus is fixed because it is so much more massive than the electrons, and only the electrons move. However this isn't strictly true and the nucleus also moves slightly in response to electron movements. A lighter nucleus like ${}^{14}\text{O}$ will move more (because it is lighter) and this will make the enegy levels slightly different.

I can't find data on oxygen to show how large the differences are, but consider the case of hydrogen and deuterium, where the nuclear mass doubles. [The ionisation energy of deuterium](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?ID=C16873179&Mask=20) is $13.603$eV while [the ionisation energy of hydrogen](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?ID=C12385136&Mask=20) is $13.598$eV so the change in the nuclear mass makes a small but measurable difference. The differences between the oxygen isotopes will be much smaller but will still exist.

Comment: Thanks for that! I can't believe I didn't even think of isotopes, I mean, of course deuterium is different to hydrogen. Wouldn't it be interesting though to have a nitrogen nucleus, with oxygen properties?